# How to add background image for newly created html button in active(pressed) state?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My script dynamically creates buttons :

```
let foo (obj) {
     let button = document.createElement('button');
     ...
}
```

those buttons got its CSS styles from obj

```
button.style.cssText = obj.cssText
```

now i need that button in active (pressed) state change its background.

background image is also from object.

```
let backgroundImage = obj.background
```

if i already got element i can just use this in CSS style :

```
#mybutton1:active {background-image: url(mybutton1back.svg)}
```

...but how can i set this dynamically ?

Comment: Use a class name in your css and apply it to the button with `button.classList.add("className")`

Comment: and just  add ''.mybutton1:active {background-image: url(mybutton1back.svg)}'' to CSS file , right ? I try it , thank you

Comment: the problem is that obj file script should got from server ,  And  client doesn't know what file it will use for background

Comment: You need to edit the question and make it very clear what your problem is then.  Try and create a **[mcve]**

Comment: If my question isn't clear then how did you answer it ?
It seems that godof23 also got no problem with my question

Comment: Even though I understood the question, I think what @Archer meant was that it's always better to reproduce the problem through a fiddle, which gives an immediate actionable.

Comment: You said `the problem is that obj file script should got from server , And client doesn't know what file it will use for background` <- That is unclear and not even mentioned in the question.

Comment: ok , i understand now . Thank you both

Comment: @godof23 I just wanted clarification really, and a code demonstration would have given that.  Also, if you're not aware you can make snippets on Stack Overflow :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pseudo css selectors styles are best handled by css. So rather than trying to mimic the `:active` css rule through js events, I decided its best to append CSS styles to the stylesheet through js.

HTML:

```
<button id="btn">
something
</button>
```

CSS:

```
button {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  padding: 2em;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: blue;
}
```

JS:

```
const button = document.getElementById('btn')
const imageUrl = 'https://www.goldenglobes.com/sites/default/files/styles/portrait_medium/public/people/cover_images/rami_malek_0601_mr._robot_13.jpg?itok=Q4NBBHxh';


const bgImageRule = `url(${imageUrl})`

const css = document.createElement("style");
css.type = "text/css";
css.innerHTML = `button#btn:active { background: ${bgImageRule}  }`;
document.head.appendChild(css);
```

PS: I hardcoded the button in the HTML, however this will work with dynamically created elements too.

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/29wdLxyo/1/)